# MemoryError: Unable to allocate GiB for an array with shape and data type float64 - on a sparse matrix

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, out-of-memory

I am working with textual data and have a document-term matrix, represented in a `scipy` sparse matrix (for memory efficiency).
I have built a class in which I train a topic model (the outcome of the topic model is the matrix `prob_word_given_topic`.

Currently, I am doing some post analysis on different models, with the following code:

```
colnames = ['Model', 'Coherence','SVD_values','Min_c0','Max_c0','Min_c1','Max_c1','Min_sv0','Max_sv0','Min_sv1','Max_sv1', 'PWGT']
analysis_two_factors = pd.DataFrame(columns=colnames)
directory = 'C:~/Images/'

#Experiment with: singular values, number of topics, weighting methods
for i, top in enumerate(range(3,28,2)):
    for weighting_method in [2,3,4,5,1]:
        print(type(top))
        one_round=[]
        model = FLSA(input_file = data_list, 
                 num_topics = top, 
                 num_words = 20, 
                 word_weighting =weighting_method, 
                 svd_factors=2, 
                 cluster_method='fcm')
        
        model.plot_svd_graph_2D(directory)
        model.plot_cluster_datapoints_graph(directory)
        one_round.append(model.setting)
        one_round.append(model.calc_coherence_value)
        one_round.append(model.s)
        one_round.append(min(model.cluster_centers[:,0]))
        one_round.append(max(model.cluster_centers[:,0]))
        one_round.append(min(model.cluster_centers[:,1]))
        one_round.append(min(model.cluster_centers[:,1]))
        one_round.append(min(model.svd_data[:,0]))
        one_round.append(max(model.svd_data[:,0]))
        one_round.append(min(model.svd_data[:,1]))
        one_round.append(min(model.svd_data[:,1]))
        one_round.append(model.prob_word_given_topic)
        analysis_two_factors.loc[i] = one_round
        print('Finished iteration',str(i))
```

However, while being in `top = 19`, I suddenly got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-687-fe7cf1e4ea7a>", line 15, in <module>
    cluster_method='fcm')

  File "<ipython-input-672-e9c098fb0e45>", line 92, in __init__
    prob_word_given_doc = np.asarray(self.sparse_weighted_matrix / self.sparse_weighted_matrix.sum(1))

  File "c:~\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 620, in __truediv__
    return self._divide(other, true_divide=True)

  File "c:~\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 599, in _divide
    return np.true_divide(self.todense(), other)

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 2.87 GiB for an array with shape (4280, 90140) and data type float64
```

This surprises me, as it did perform all previous iterations in the loop and also `self.sparse_weighted_matrix` is a sparse matrix (`dok_matrix`), so I dont expect such high memory requirements here. Can somebody explain why I get this error? And what I can do to overcome the problem?

```
prob_word_given_doc = np.asarray(self.sparse_weighted_matrix / self.sparse_weighted_matrix.sum(1))
```

Comment: I think it's the .todense step that's requiring too much memory

Comment: Your traceback is cut off, but I guess it's the `FLSA` function.  You didn't identify the sparse matrix, but apparently this function scales it by the row sum.  That  `M/M.sum((1)` is done on dense matrices, not the original sparse one.  `scipy.sparse` does not implement a element-wise sparse division.

Comment: If this error is new, it may be because the sparse matrix is larger than usual, or something else is taking up too much memory.  3G for a dense array of that size is reasonable.